# Search for parts of a list in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a list of book titles, and i want to find which of them exists in my index.

the mapping is:

```
"book": {
    "properties": {
                  "title":{"type":"string"}, 
                  "author":{"type":"string"}}}
```

I could iterate and check each one with

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/book/_search' 
-d '{"query":{"match":{"title":"my title"}}}
```

But assuming the list of titles i long, how can I do this in bulk and get a list of which ones got a hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run several `match` queries against your title field, combining them with a `bool` query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/book/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "should" : [
            {
               "match" : {
                  "title" : "Title one"
               }
            },
            {
               "match" : {
                  "title" : "Title two"
               }
            },
            {
               "match" : {
                  "title" : "Title three"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

Of course, a `match` query will match on any books whose `title` field contains one word in the query string, so you may want to use `match_phrase` instead:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/book/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "should" : [
            {
               "match_phrase" : {
                  "title" : "Title one"
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase" : {
                  "title" : "Title two"
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase" : {
                  "title" : "Title three"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

This will search for the exact phrase: the same words in the same order.